# Change iPod default keyboard with custom keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipod, ipod-touch

I want to change the iPOD default keyboard with custom keyboard that can have number only. Like telephone dialed like this:

[image]

iPOD default keyboard is like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I remember the need to specify a pattern when defining the input, as well as setting the type to `number`. So:

`<input type="number" pattern="\d*"/>`

Should do the trick, otherwise you can also use:

`<input type="tel">`

But this method isn't really solid cross-browser.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it opens default keyboard of ipod and i want to hide it and use custom keyboard.

Comment: You mean a custom-designed keyboard? I'm afraid that's not possible, at least not in a semantic way. That would include a load of hacky stuff.